# How to update a row with multiple images which has only single image inserted initially in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with columns id,image and organisation name.I have inserted single image for each organisation initially but i need to update it with multiple images for each organisation.I am using php ver 5.4.16 and mysql ver 5.6.12.

Comment: you can update image field by appending the next image name

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a separator, for example use comma and store it like this in your table :

```
id    image                                     organization
 1    path_to/img1.png                          org_name1
 2    path_to/img1.png,path_to/img2.png         org_name2
```

and later, after you extract the record, use explode function to extract it to an array like this :

```
$images = explode(",", $data->image);
```

PS : please give enough length for the image field, for example, give it varchar(4000), this is to make sure there will be no string truncation

Comment: thanks budiantoip lemme explain the real problem initially i have not used the multiple file upload option then i started using it so in the same table i have inserted multiple images in different rows for same oragnisation.But i need to update by  uploading more images for an organisation  keeping its  old images as it is.

Comment: Yes, I can understand your problem. Therefore, I have designed a solution with minimum effort, the idea is to append the image filename to the image field. I'd like to ask you, did you store the image directly into the image field? or did you store the path to the image into that field? Because my solution works only for the the latter :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the table in two and use the id of your table as foreign key in the new image table. ("normalization" and "relations" should be your search tags) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Or if you can't you should use json to insert multiple content. http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: thanks for the reply but i have already inserted more data in it is there any other provisions so that i can update more images in the same table itself

Comment: As I said ... put all your image strings into an array and convert that to json format. Insert your json in the database. If you pull your data just decode the json back into an array. Thats it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new table named "image" with columns :

```
- id_img
- image
- ref_organisation_id (foreign_key)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution, in my opinion, to your problem would be to slightly redesign your database schema - the existing table will not be able to store multiple images for the same company judging by the overview of the tables you gave in the question.

There ought to be a table for orgainisations and another table for images associated with those organisations. The images table would have a key that links to the organisations table.

A very quickly put together example database structure

```
+----+------------------+
| id | name             |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | ACME Web Company |
|  2 | ACME ISP         |
+----+------------------+


+----+--------+------------+
| id | org_id | image      |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |      1 | logo.jpg   |
|  2 |      1 | banner.jpg |
|  3 |      1 | badge.png  |
|  4 |      2 | logo.jpg   |
|  5 |      2 | banner.gif |
+----+--------+------------+

create table if not exists `organisations` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=innodb auto_increment=3 default charset=utf8;

insert into `organisations` (`id`, `name`) values
    (1, 'acme web company'),
    (2, 'acme isp');

create table if not exists `org_images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
  `org_id` int(10) unsigned not null,
  `image` varchar(50) not null,
  primary key (`id`),
  key `org_id` (`org_id`),
  constraint `fk_org` foreign key (`org_id`) references `organisations` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine=innodb auto_increment=6 default charset=utf8;

insert into `org_images` (`id`, `org_id`, `image`) values
    (1, 1, 'logo.jpg'),
    (2, 1, 'banner.jpg'),
    (3, 1, 'badge.png'),
    (4, 2, 'logo.jpg'),
    (5, 2, 'banner.gif');
```