# How to edit a row by uploading more images keeping its already inserted images as they are using php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with my edit option in my project.I have a table with three columns id,organisation name and image.I have inserted multiple images for organisation using multiple image upload,now i need to edit the rows and i need to add more images for each organisation.how can i do it without affecting the previously inserted images in php and mysql
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where's your code? [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35058425/edit) your question with the *relevant* code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a row with multiple images which has only single image inserted initially in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056664/how-to-update-a-row-with-multiple-images-which-has-only-single-image-inserted-in)